# Are JNA Objects pass by reference or by value inside java code

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, jna

Can i pass the JNA Objects around for initialization and writing inside of java?

-> Is it possible having a method that initializes each member of a struct and other methods to fill the arrays and so on.

I found no answer on google / nor https://jna.java.net/

Comment: What do you mean by "JNA Objects"?  JNA provides tools to manipulate native functions _and_ data.

Comment: eg the struct object, do i pass around, inside java, the same struct or do i pass around copies of the same struct -> do i manipulate the same object or do i create copies of the values with a new memory location.

Answer (score 0):

You can synch native memory to a Java object, but you can't overlay a Java object on native memory and you *shouldn't* expose java object memory directly to native code.  What JNA does is associate native memory with Java objects and provide methods to synch the two.

Raw memory:

```
Pointer memory = new Memory(128);
memory.setInt(0, 1234)
```

Structured data:

```
MyStructure s = new MyStructure();
s.int_field = 1234;
s.write();

s = new MyStructure(native_pointer);
s.read();
System.out.println("Field: %s", s.int_field);
```

Comment: could you provide a simple example how the syncing should be done?
also, if i pass a struct object in java around and change the values, do i change the actual values or do i change the only the local version (as java normally works)